# How to create movement speed limits when a character overlaps the surface of the water

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

How to adjust the speed of the character when crossing a cube with water?
And how to make it move more slowly on the surface of the water, while leaving the ability to move with Shift?

[Speed up movement when pressing Shift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzIsf.png)

[Water surface blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1IRu.jpg)

[Water surface blueprint components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn82q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put an `OnComponentBeginOverlap` event on 'BP_WaterRegion' that checks what kind of actor it's just overlapped with. If it's the player character then you can set the MaxWalkSpeed variable on the character from there. The `OnComponentEndOverlap` event should be self-explanatory now.

If you select 'WaterMesh' you should find these events at the bottom of the Details panel.

[image: Use overlap events to set walk speed on character.]

(It's a while since I've worked in UE - you might need to connect the output from the cast node to the == node instead.)